# Does Google have access to the mac/cpu serial numbers and similar to that?

Tags: google

Recently I logged in my gmail account on chrome browser and checked the devices linked to my gmail account.surprisingly in the linked devices and in the recent logins it shown my laptop hostname. I just confused seeing that and then I tried logging gmail on Firefox and it doesn’t showed the hostname in the recent logins. So clearly google is able to access the laptop hostname through chrome. Is Chrome browser giving every detail like MAC address ,cpu serial numbers of the PC to google?

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704859/how-does-google-know-my-computerss-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704859/how-does-google-know-my-computerss-name)

Comment: Yeah just checked and  It doesn’t answer my question. The context is different here

Comment: It's likely that they do... "We collect information about the apps, browsers, and devices you use to access Google services..."  See this link: https://policies.google.com/privacy  I tend to think of this as a good thing for security purposes.  (It helps them to know when a new device logs into your account so they can notify you.)  One thing they also mention is also a unique ID they generate for every chrome browser on install.

Comment: Although not directly related to this question, see this blog post by Bruce Schneier for some interesting reading on this general subject, and consider if this changes the way that you think of your relationship with Google:  https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/12/feudal_sec.html

Comment: CPU serial number? No. That hasn't been a thing for decades.